# How to use multiple favicon.ico sizes with favicon_link_tag helper in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, favicon

My problem is simply the favicon not showing up when using the `favicon_link_tag` and the multiple sizes option.

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico', sizes: '16x16 32x32' %>
```

The files were labeled `favicon-16.ico` and `favicon-32.ico` respectively. These images are in the `app/assets/images` folder. Am I labeling them wrong? Is this a limitation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution does not lie in Rails magic but in the way you manage the `favicon.ico` file. [A single ICO file can contain several pictures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491740(v=vs.85).aspx). This is what web browsers expect. In particular, `favicon.ico` should contain three versions of the same icon: 16x16, 32x32 and 48x48. Regarding the `sizes` attribute, it was introduced in HTML5 and is dedicated to the PNG icons. Not `favicon.ico`.

**The code**

The basic definition is enough:

```
favicon_link_tag '/path/to/favicon.ico'
```

Make sure the path is consistent with `app/assets/images`, I must admit I don't know where it is mapped.

**The picture**

You can first prepare three PNG pictures (let's call them `16x16.png`, `32x32.png` and `48x48.png`) and merge them with a tool such as `icotool` (on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install icoutils`):

```
icotool -c -o favicon.ico 16x16.png 32x32.png 48x48.png
```

If you don't want to bother with `icotool` and you don't have any other solution at hand, you can also use this [favicon generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/). Just keep the generated `favicon.ico` and leave the rest if you are not interested. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.

Answer (score 8):

One idea would be to use the the [link](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) philippe_b posted to generate the various images. Place them in app/assets/images/

Then, in your **application.html.erb** put the following code between the `<head> </head>` tags in your application:

```
<% %w(57 60 72 76 114 120 144 152 180).each do |s| %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag "apple-touch-icon-#{s}x#{s}.png", rel: 'apple-touch-icon', type: 'image/png', sizes: "#{s}x#{s}" %>
<% end %>

<% %w(16 32).each do |s| %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag "favicon-#{s}x#{s}.png", rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', sizes: "#{s}x#{s}" %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to use the assets precompiled in `app/assets/images/` without having to place them in `app/public/`

Please note that I am not dealing with the Android or Windows images here, only basic favicon and apple touch images. For more information on suggested apple touch icon sizes, [check this website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#/apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27).